# How to cut a image with a color pattern to create a Jigsaw piece in android?

Tags: java, android, image

I want to create programmatically in Android Jigsaw puzzle pieces from a image using other image with the patterns of the pieces.
This is the image pattern of the pieces:

**Pattern all images**

[image]

I need create a image for each piece.

I can get a single piece using a image with the pattern of only a piece with color for the area of the piece and transparent color in the rest of the image with this code:

```java
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mascara2.getWidth(), mascara2.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);      
c.drawBitmap(cuadro, 0, 0, null);
Paint maskPaint = new Paint();
maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
c.drawBitmap(mascara2, 0, 0, maskPaint);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null)
```

**With this pattern:**

[image]

but I need use only 1 image (the first image) with all pieces to cut the piezes of the puzzle

Thanks!!!!